# When was the oldest person ever to have a FIDE rating born?

Tags: rating, fide

Specifically, one FIDE rated player was born before all other FIDE rated players. Who was it and when was he born?

Comment: Do you mean (a) the oldest *living* FIDE rated player or (b) the player who was  born first (and now likely dead) out of all players who ever had a rating?

Comment: @user1583209 My use of the past tense in the question ("who was it") gives you your answer. Had I meant the oldest living FIDE rated player that is what I would have asked but that would have been foolish since the answer could change between me asking and somebody answering. My question can only ever have one answer. So, no, the answer is not the German player Gehard Vogel (born 1910, rating 1479).

Comment: Ok, could you answer the question from this data: http://www.olimpbase.org/index.html?http%3A%2F%2Fwww.olimpbase.org%2FElo%2Fsummary.html ?

Comment: ...or this data: http://www.mark-weeks.com/chess/ratings/

Comment: @user1583209 This website - http://www.chessmaniac.com/long-lived-chess-players/ - says Vogel died in 2010, so you already see the problem with "living". The FIDE rating website lists him but he's been dead for 7 years.

Comment: @user1583209 You should use the best source for FIDE ratings that you can. Estimated FIDE ratings for historic figures are not FIDE ratings. For instance some sites will tell you what Paul Morphy's FIDE rating should be. Except that Morphy died in 1884 and the first FIDE ratings were published in 1971 so he never had a FIDE rating. Chess Informant is the earliest reliable source of official FIDE ratings.

Comment: He may not be the oldest, but grandmaster Friedrich Saemisch: https://www.olimpbase.org/Elo/player/Saemisch,%20Friedrich.html was awarded a 2200 elo-rating on the first list in 1971 when (and never played a rated game afterwards). He was born in 1896, we can start digging for older players. I don't believe there are too many of them..

Comment: Esteban Canal was a few months older than Saemisch. https://www.olimpbase.org/Elo/player/Canal,%20Esteban.html

Comment: You are not asking about the oldest person to ever have a FIDE rating, you are asking about the earliest born.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've no proof him to be the earliest born of them all, but after browsing the earliest FIDE rating lists, my candidate would be Esteban [Canal](https://www.olimpbase.org/Elo/player/Canal,%20Esteban.html):

Born in 1896, April the 19th, the Peruvian master was 75 when he entered the first published [list](https://www.olimpbase.org/Elo/Elo197107e.html) in July 1971 with an Elo of 2270.

He beats grandmaster Friedrich [Saemisch](https://www.olimpbase.org/Elo/player/Saemisch,%20Friedrich.html) by five months.